# Keycloak Cannot Work in Docker compose file. How can I fix it?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to write keycloak configuration in my docker-compose.yml. Here is the command which works :

```
docker run -p 8181:8080 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2 start-dev
```

I tried to write it in `docker-compose.yml` but it didn't work.

```
keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - "8181:8080"
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - "keycloak"


networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? Where are you defining your `backend` network? Why are you using that when it doesn't appear in your working command line? Why are you running `start-dev` on the command line but not in your `docker-compose.yaml`?

Comment: @larsks I didn't open http://localhost:8181/. It says that This site can’t be reached.

Comment: @larsks I cannot fix the issue. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer

```
keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - "8181:8080"
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - "keycloak"
    command:
      - start-dev
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks for the answer! Can you please, let me know how did you came up with this solution?

Comment: The `command` instruction was all i was missing. In the basic tutorial from KC, you're told to start the container: `docker run ... start-dev` but you can't do that from docker-compose. This allows you to fill that gap. Thank you!